# Trying to highlight cells identical to the one selected

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find a way to highlight all cells identical to the current cell selected using any conditional formatting, macros or anything else.

I've spent the past couple of hours searching for a way to do this with "current cell" and "active cell" but can't seem to find anything based on cell selection

Comment: what do you mean by "one selected" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- matching selected cell in **`B2`**
- selected range: **`A1:C`**
- custom formula: **`=IF(A1=$B$2,1)`**

[image: 0]

Comment: Yes, Something like this. However if i click on C5 i want it to highlight C3, B5, C5 and B7

Comment: @Charles that is not possible on selection. conditional formatting needs to be always pre-set in advance

Comment: What about some kind of Script, Macro or Add-on?

Comment: @Charles nope, not possible either. it's just not possible to have it on select. closest you can get is to press ctrl+f and type in what you want to find.